# Android/Joda time - Convert dateTime to my local DateTime

Tags: android, datetime, timezone, jodatime

I am trying to convert server date string to my local/device set local time but without success. I am using Joda time library.

What i am trying to do:

```
private static String FORMAT_DATE_SERVER = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";

public static DateTime parseServerDateToLocal(String raw_date) {

    DateTime result = DateTime.parse(raw_date, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(FORMAT_DATE_SERVER)).withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault());

    return result;
}
```

Still returns the DateTime from the server. I cant manage to make it to return the proper hour/datetime.

I read many post about this, but i didnt manage to make it simple, clean and working.

Comment: If you use Joda-Time then keep in mind that this lib might use completely different timezone data compared with those on your device. The device data are often outdated but maybe the user has choosen another timezone/offset to set the local time to a correct value to compensate for outdated data. Have you thought about this?

Comment: hmmm. what do you suggest to handle this situation?

Comment: Before suggesting anything, can you be so kind to tell us concrete inputs and data? What is "raw_date", what is the system timezone id? What is `java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(dateTime.getMillis())`? What does `DateTimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(dateTime.getMillis())` yield? Which offset and local timestamp do you expect instead?

Comment: @MenoHochschild, The raw_data = "2015-06-18T08:33:49Z", my timezone is +2h. But this timezone should change depending on user, so it should not matter my offset and local time stamp, since it needs to be generic.

Comment: The question still stands if you have verified that `java.util.TimeZone` and `DateTimeZone` yield the same offset or not. Even if you use a broadcast-receiver for device timezone changes (which is for example built into the library Joda-Time-Android of D. Lew) an offset delta is still possible due to the different underlying timezone data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution i have found:

in your application class, or somewhere else, initialise JodaTimeAndroid:

```
JodaTimeAndroid.init(this);
```

after this initialisation the date will be automatically converted to your zone, with proper offset. This is how you parse the data then:

```
private static String FORMAT_DATE_SERVER = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
private static String raw_date = "2015-06-18T08:52:27Z";

public static DateTime parseServerDateToLocal(String raw_date) {
         return DateTime.parse(raw_date, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(FORMAT_DATE_SERVER));
}
```

In my case, with offset (+2h), the returned data is:

> 2015-06-18T10:52:27.000+02:00

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

Example 
Converting a date String of the format "2011-06-23T15:11:32" to out time zone.

```
private String getDate(String dateString) {
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date value = null;
try {
    value = formatter.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mmaa");
dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
String dt = dateFormatter.format(value);

return dt;
}
```

Comment: How can i return DateTime (from Joda) as result?

Comment: you cal like this  String mylocaldate=getDate("youdate in string"); you got result is mylocaldate. you can  use that mylocaldate value.

Comment: Sorry im not following. I need a function that takes in consideration a String date, and return an org.joda.time.DateTime object.